# Create a new command with one argument that can be used as a command itself?

Tags: macros

My idea is to create a new command with one argument that can be used as a command itself.

For example something like `\newcommand{\formattext}[1]{\#1{#1}}` creates a new command called formattext which should be used as `\formattext{textit}` to give me the same result of `\texit{textit}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\formattext}[1]{\#1{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \formattext{textit}
\end{document}
```

I want the result to look like this by using `\formattext{textit}`:

[image]

But instead I get this:

[image]

Is this even somehow possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\csname` primitive constructs control sequence tokens, so

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\formattext}[1]{\csname#1\endcsname{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \formattext{textit}
\end{document}
```

[image]